# Laravel - How can select data in 4 tables at a time using Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have 4 tables: `products`, `attributes`, `attribute_groups`, `attribute_product`.

**Product - Attribute:** Many to Many.

**Attribute - Attribute Group:** One to Many.

Using Eloquent ORM, how can I fetch a nested object to show data like that:

```
@foreach($product->attributeGroups as $attributeGroup)

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{ $attributeGroup->name }}:</label>
        {{ Form::select('attributes[$attributeGroup->id][]', $attributeGroup->attributes, null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) }}
    </div>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your Product model, simply added the following

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
     protected $with = ['attributeGroups.attributes'];

     public function attributeGroups() {
          return $this->belongsToMany('AttributeGroup');
     }

}
```

This will auto/eager load your relationships with every request of the Product resource model.

Here is an example of what your AttributeGroup eloquent model should look like.

```
class AttributeGroup extends Eloquent {
      protected $table = 'attribute_groups';

      public function attributes() {
           return $this->belongsToMany('Attribute');
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But...
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attributeGroups()`

Comment: Thank you. But in my application, the `AttributeGroup` does not have relationship with `Product`.

A product has many attributes and a attribute belongs to a attribute group. I want to when I go to a product detail page. I will select all attributes of this product and group by attribute group.